# Control a paper-checkbox's state

Tags: polymer, paper-elements

I'm trying to setup an element with a `paper-checkbox` inside of it. I want the checkbox's checked state to be controlled by the response of an ajax call.

HTML:

```
<epic-list-episode checked="<%= episode.seen? %>">
  <p><strong><%= episode.show.name %></strong></p>
</epic-list-episode>
```

Custom element:

```
<polymer-element name="epic-list-episode" attributes="checked">

  <template>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="epic-list-episode.css.scss" />
    <div horizontal layout center>
      <div flex>
        <content></content>
      </div>
      <div vertical layout>
        <paper-checkbox checked?="{{checked === 'true'}}" on-change="{{changeHandler}}"></paper-checkbox>
      </div>
    </div>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      changeHandler: function(event) {
        //Send ajax, wait for error/success callback
        //checkbox.checked = response from ajax
      }
    });
  </script>

</polymer-element>
```

How can this be achieved? I've tried `return false` but the checkbox still does its toggle animation.

To clarify, here is the flow i want:

1. Checkbox is unchecked
2. I click the checkbox (I don't want it to toggle yet)
3. Ajax request is sent off
4. Wait for the callback
5. If it's successful, toggle the state of the checkbox

Comment: What do you mean by " the checkbox still does its toggle animation."?

Comment: The checkbox animates from between unchecked/checked. I've updated the question with some clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need that `checked` attribute at all.

What you can do is, when the `on-change` is called, set the `checked` property of the `paper-checkbox` back to its previous value. And then after the ajax callback, set it back to what it should be.

```
changeHandler: function (event, detail, sender) {
    this.$.checkbox.checked = !this.$.checkbox.checked;

    // give the checkbox a little loading animation
    var loading = new CoreAnimation();
    loading.duration = 750;
    loading.easing = 'ease-in';
    loading.keyframes = [{ opacity: 1, transform: "scale(1)" }, { opacity: 0.4, transform: "scale(0.9)" }];
    loading.direction = 'alternate';
    loading.iterations = '1000';
    loading.target = this.$.checkbox;
    loading.play();

    // give it a little delay to act like a callback
    this.job('delay', function () {
        // stop the animation
        loading.finish();

        this.$.checkbox.checked = !this.$.checkbox.checked;
    }, 3000);
}
```

Note that I have also included some animation code to make the user feel like the `paper-checkbox` is doing something, for a better user experience. Please see this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/noyadonizi/1/edit) for a working example.

Comment: The checked attribute is there to set the initial state on page load. Some are checked, and some are not. `set the checked property of the paper-checkbox back to its previous value.` is what I was looking for I guess. I also didn't know about `CoreAnimation`. Thanks :) Will accept when I get a change to try it.

Answer (score 1):

there are a few ways to actually go about it. i have made this plunker to show the 2 ways i go about doing this. http://plnkr.co/edit/xqHCSvs63u4bdFJYM6TF?p=preview

using declarative binding

```
<paper-checkbox checked="{{checked}}" on-change="{{changeHandler}}"></paper-checkbox>
```

in your script

```
this.checked = true;
```

and pure js

```
<paper-checkbox id="box" on-change="{{changeHandler}}"></paper-checkbox>
```

then in your script

```
var box = document.querySelector("#box");
box.checked = true;
```